# Mathematica: How to get element of nested list

Tags: list, nested, wolfram-mathematica

I have a little problem with getting element from nested list. I have list like this:

```
list{{4, 1}, {3, 2}, {3, 3}, {4, 4}}
```

I want to get single number from this list, e.g. 4. How can I get it? I've tried something like

```
list[[1]]
```

and other things. I've tried many times and failed. Would be great if anyone could show me this. Thanks!

Comment: start here. http://reference.wolfram.com/language/howto/WorkWithLists.html  Mathematica docs are so good I dont understand why people post here without even looking at the docs. voting to close.

Comment: You can read mathematica doc: ?Take

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not valid Mathematica syntax. Do you mean this?

```
list = {{4, 1}, {3, 2}, {3, 3}, {4, 4}}
```

If so, then notice that the numbers in that list are "two levels down" so you have to use the `[[_]]` operator twice. Either like `list[[1]][[2]]` or I think `list[[1,2]]` works too.